# How to run JavaScript as a server side script language on SourceForge.NET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sourceforge

As I known, JavaScript is a client-side scripting language. But, some days ago, I have heared that JavaScript is a server-side script language.

I don't understand about it... To know it, I have search Google, and I known that Node.JS can be used as a server-side script language. I have run some script with Node.JS (on Windows XP) successfully.

So, I tried to run it with a real server... I have posted all script (which are written in Node.JS) into SourceForge.NET. But, I don't know how do run it?

Can you help me to answer: "Does SourceForge.NET supports Node.JS? If can, please show me how to run with this server?".

---

I tried to run it with SourceForge.NET for only fun.

Comment: Isn't SourceForge.NET a generic hosting service for OSS projects and not an HTTPD that you can *run* your own code on? Or is there some server software with the same name? Possibly something related to Microsoft's .NET framework. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a means of running JavaScript programs. It is commonly used to write HTTP servers.

If you have written code to use Node.js then you need to run it with Node.js for it to work.

If you want to involve some other kind of server then you would have to proxy requests made to it onto Node.js (e.g. with Apache's ProxyPass directive)… but that typically eliminates the reasons that people choose to use Node.js in the first place.

If you want to use Node.js in production then you will usually need to be hosting your site on a VM or a dedicated server. Shared hosting won't usually give you enough access to run Node.js.

Comment: Does SourceForge.NET supports Node.JS? Does SourceForge.NET allows project-developer install more Apache modules?

Comment: @rad: I don't understand. As far as I know sourceforge.net isn't a web host. You used to be able to host wordpress applications on sourceforge but they stopped that service last year. What do you think sourceforge is? If you want to host node web applications there are free hosts that supports node.js. The two big ones I know of are google cloud and redhat openshift (google for them). You can also try hosting a vm on amazon. They let you create a small one for free for one year. After that you have to pay. I'd personally try out openshift first - it's free forever.